# convert show-single-picture function to show-multiple-pictures function (from directory) php

Tags: php

I want to convert a function `random_pic()` to `random_pics()`, so instead of displying a single picture, this function displays 10 random pictures of the directory

**DISPLAYS SINGLE RANDOM PICTURE** working

```
function random_pic($dir){
$files = glob("../gifs/".$dir.'/*.gif');
//single picture
$file = array_rand($files);
return "<img src='".$files[$file]."' />$dir<br/>";
 }

echo random_pic("*");
```

**CONVERTING TO RANDOM PICTURES**  not working

```
function random_pic($dir){
$file=array();
$gifs=array();
$mdir = "../gifs/".$dir."/";
$files = glob($mdir.'*.gif');



foreach ($files as $count => $gif){
 $file[$count] = array_rand($files);//how to?

if($count<10){
$gifs[] = " $count <img src='". $gif."' /><br/>";
}
}
$gifs=implode("",$gifs);
return $gifs;

}
```

How do I make it work?

Comment: Either `echo` within the function, or concatenate onto a string each time through the loop and then return that string after the loop.

Comment: mmm...meaning ?

Comment: You're `return`ing within the loop.  That ends the function, so you're only hitting the first iteration of your loop.

Comment: @PatrickQ check the update please, it returns ten pictures but they are not random

Comment: Before the loop, `shuffle($files);`  Remove the first line currently within your loop.

Comment: Ya it works. thank you...feel free to post an answer to mark it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, you need to `return` *after* the loop, not inside it.  To accomplish the randomization, you can use `shuffle()`.

```
function random_pic($dir){
    $gifs = "";
    $mdir = "../gifs/".$dir."/";
    $files = glob($mdir.'*.gif');

    // this randomizes the array of files
    suffle($files);

    foreach ($files as $count => $gif){

        if($count<10){
            // that concatenates on to gifs the string 
            $gifs .= " $count <img src='". $gif."' /><br/>";
        }
    }

    // return the final gifs string after it as been assem
    return $gifs;

}
```